# Que implica que una clase este obsoleta (Deprecated)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy verificando si existe conexión a internet, para ello estoy siguiendo la documentación , ah funcionado muy bien a pesar de que en mi proyecto me marca NetworkInfo como deprecado.

```
val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        val isConnected: Boolean = activeNetwork?.isConnectedOrConnecting == true
```

Si leí la nota de la [documentacion](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type?hl=es-419#DetermineConnection) que dice que

```
"getActiveNetworkInfo() ya no está disponible en Android 10..."
```

Supongo que es lo mismo que decir que esta deprecado o talvez no. Endiendo que deprecado es algo considerado antiguo y que se encuentra en proceso de sustitución o retirada, sin embargo me quedan las siguientes dudas.

1. En este caso, que "NO ESTE DISPONIBLE EN ANDROID 10" significa que:
   No podre usarlo  donde, en el editor me lo marcara como deprecado ,
   en un dispositivo Android 10, mi dispositivo es Android 10 y al
   parecer funciona perfecto.
2. Si uso "NetworkCallbacks para las apps orientadas a Android 10 (API
   nivel 29) o versiones posteriores", como recomienda ya no funcionara
   o causara errores en dispositivos con Android 9 y anteriores.
3. Entonces si uso NetworkInfo en estos momentos o en un futuro cercano
   mi app tendrá errores inesperados con las nuevas versiones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te indica el mensaje, en Android 10, el uso de la clase NetWorkInfo y sus métodos es obsoleto, ahora debe usar la clase ConnectivityManager y el método getNetworkCapabilities() de la clase NetworkCapabilities.

Esta es una funciòn actualizada la cual puedes usar para detectar conexiòn a internet

```
fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR")
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI")
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET")
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Revisa esta respuesta:

[Como revisar conectividad en Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141970/check-internet-connectivity-android-in-kotlin/57237708#57237708)

Con respecto a tus preguntas, me parece que las 3 estàn relacionadas:

> En este caso, que "NO ESTE DISPONIBLE EN ANDROID 10" significa que: No
> podre usarlo donde, en el editor me lo marcara como deprecado , en un
> dispositivo Android 10, mi dispositivo es Android 10 y al parecer
> funciona perfecto.
>
> Si uso "NetworkCallbacks para las apps orientadas a Android 10 (API
> nivel 29) o versiones posteriores", como recomienda ya no funcionara o
> causara errores en dispositivos con Android 9 y anteriores.
>
> Entonces si uso NetworkInfo en estos momentos o en un futuro cercano
> mi app tendrá errores inesperados con las nuevas versiones.

Si tu aplicaciòn tiene definido `targetSdkVersion 29` (Android 10) y tratas de usar tu app en un dispositivo con Android 10, no funcionarìa, si funciona es que tienes definido `targetSdkVersion` menor a 29, pero en algùn momento tendràs que actualizar, por lo tanto se sugiere cambiar los mètodos o clases que se marquen como obsoletos.

Revisa:
[Cambios en los comportamientos: apps orientadas a la API nivel 29 y posteriores](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10)

Comment: Gracias, por la aclaración, me servirá mucho.

Comment: Excelente Redox, saludos